# Jasmine testing matcher for throw someObject

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a function which throws some object in certain cases. I wrote a jasmine expect matcher with toThrow but its not working. Not sure why its failing. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  fit("The 'toThrow' matcher is for some object", function() {
    function baz(x) {   // this is the function to test
      if(x === 1) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        throw {status: 515};
      }
    };
    expect(baz(1)).toBe(1); // matched perfect.
    expect(baz(2)).toThrow({status: 515}); // failing with message Error: "[object Object] thrown"
  });
```

How to write matcher for function call baz(2)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, you have to give the reference to the function to `expect`, not the return value of the function.

see https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/matchers.html#toThrow

Example

```
function error() {
   throw 'ERROR';
}
expect(error).toThrow('ERROR')
```

For your case, you can wrap your function call into another function. You can directly inline the declaration of that function inside the `expect` argument:

```
expect(() => baz(2)).toThrow({status: 515});
// equivalent with
expect(function(){ baz(2) }).toThrow({status: 515});
```

Another way is to use `.bind` to attach parameters to the function without calling it.

```
expect(baz.bind(null, 2)).toThrow({status: 515});
//              ^^^^  ^
//           context  first parameter
```